# ngrams() function not found in NLP R package

Tags: r, nlp, package

Here is the code straight from the NLP.pdf. I typed into the RStudio console. I am puzzled.

```
library("NLP")
library("tm")
s <- "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
w <- strsplit(s, " ", fixed = TRUE)[[1L]]
ngrams(w, 3L)
```

> Error: could not find function "ngrams"

Comment: This issue was obsolete a year ago, could you please close it by accepting @MrFlick's answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ngrams` function was added in version 0.1-7. Make sure you have at least that version of the package installed. you can check which version you are running by looking at `sessionInfo()` after you run `library(NLP)`. If your version is out of date, you can use `update.packages()` to update your local package.

It's usually better to check the documentation that's included with your installed package rather than a separate PDF file. You can bring up the help for a package with `help(package="NLP")`. This would have confined that the function is not in the version you have installed.